# Positioning four buttons in a cross like pattern but close to each other

Tags: java, swing

i am trying to the an exercise where by you move a ball on a canvas..i have gotten the part of moving the ball but i am unable to place the move up and the move down buttons in the positions. if you run this code you will see that the "move up" and "move down" buttons are far from the rest of the buttons.so i would like to bring them closer to the other buttons(i want to adjust their vertical position while maintaining their horizontal position)here is my code..please help and thank you in advance..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; import javax.swing.*;

public class CGmoveABall extends JFrame {

    public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 340;
    public static final Color LINE_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    public static final Color CANVAS_BACKGROUND = Color.CYAN;
    private int x =150, y = CANVAS_HEIGHT/4;  // top-left (x, y)
    private int size = 100; 

    private DrawCanvas canvas;  

    public CGmoveABall() {

    FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,1,1);

    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(f1);
    JPanel CentrePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel DownPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    FlowLayout f2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,3,3); 

    JButton btnUp = new JButton("Move Up");
    btnUp.setSize(10,3);

    btnPanel.add(btnUp);      
    btnUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            y -= 10;
            System.out.println("ciao1");
            canvas.repaint();
            requestFocus();
        }
    });


    JButton btnLeft = new JButton("Move Left ");
    CentrePanel.add(btnLeft);
    btnLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x -= 10;
            // y -= 10;
            canvas.repaint();
            requestFocus();          }
        });


        JButton btnRight = new JButton("Move Right");
        CentrePanel.add(btnRight,f1);
        btnRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x += 10;
                //  y += 10;
                canvas.repaint();
                requestFocus();          }
            });


        JButton btnDn = new JButton("Move Down");
        DownPanel.add(btnDn); 
        btnDn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("ciao2");
                y += 10;
                canvas.repaint();
                requestFocus();
            }
        });   



        canvas = new DrawCanvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));
        cp.add(canvas,f1);
        cp.add(btnPanel,f1);
        cp.add(CentrePanel,f1);
        cp.add( DownPanel,f1);
        cp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, 2*CANVAS_HEIGHT));

        pack();

        /*   // "this" JFrame fires KeyEvent
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        x -= 10;
                        y -= 10;
                        repaint();
                    break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        x  += 10;
                        y += 10;
                        repaint();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });*/

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Handle the CLOSE button
        setTitle("Move a Line");
        pack();           // pack all the components in the JFrame
        setVisible(true); // show it
        requestFocus();   // set the focus to JFrame to receive KeyEvent
    }

    /**
     * DrawCanvas (inner class) is a JPanel used for custom drawing
     */

    private class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);  // paint parent's background
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);  // draw a circle
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would an absolute layout help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all some general problems:

```
cp.add(canvas,f1);
```

That is not how you use the add method. The second parameter is the "constraint" that is used by the layout manager, not the actual layout manager itself. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more general information. Maybe start with the BorderLayout to see how the constraint is specified.

```
cp.add(CentrePanel,f1);
cp.add( DownPanel,f1);
```

Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of your names are correct others are not. Be consistent!!!

```
JButton btnDn = new JButton("Move Down");
```

Variable names should be meaningful. Don't shorten names. Use `"buttonDown"`. You called your panel "downPanel". Again be consistent. You don't save space with short names.

> i am unable to place the move up and the move down buttons in the positions

You can use multiple panels with different layout managers to achieve your layout.

So I would use the default layout manager of the frame which is a `BorderLayout`.

Then I would add your game panel to the `CENTER`. Next I would create a separate panel for the buttons and then add the buttons to that panel and add that panel to the `PAGE_END`.

This way you break down the components into logical panels.

So your code would be something like:

```
Containercp = getContentPane();
//cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));
//cp.add(canvas, f1);
//cp.add(btnPanel,f1);
//cp.add(CentrePanel,f1);
//cp.add(DownPanel,f1);
add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
Box pageEnd = Box.createVerticalBox();
btnUp.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
pageEnd.add(btnUp);
pageEnd.add(CentrePanel);
btnDn.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
pageEnd.add(btnDn);
add(pageEnd, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Note I add the up/down buttons directly to the panel, but I need to change the alignment to .5f to center the button horizontally in the panel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.it works the way i wanted it work.Just to get more in depth understanding of how things work,at the moment my "moveUp" button is attached to the canvas pane and the "movedown" button is attached to the bottom of the "Container cp"..I have tried to adjust their positions using the setAlignmentY method but it has no effect on them.In short,i want to create some distance between the "moveDn" buttom and the bottom of the "Container cp" and some distance between the "moveUp" button and the canvas frame,how would i go about this?thank you in advance

Comment: `it works the way i wanted it` - glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: `i want to create some distance` - read the tutorial link I proved on "Layout Managers". With a BoxLayout you can create a "vertical strut" to give space before/after components. Or in the tutorial you can also check out the section on `How to Use Borders` which give space around a panel.